# Git returned error: 401 (curl_result = 22, http_code = 401, sha1 =

Tags: git

I don't understand why the command `git pull origin master` stopped working my computer ever since I upgraded to ubuntu 12.04.  The command works from every other computer and server.  Here's what I did on my computer:

```
mkdir gittest
cd gittest
git init
git remote add origin http://johnuser@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject
git pull origin master
```

I am prompted for a password. So i give the correct password.  But my own personal ubuntu 12.04, I get this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 (curl_result = 22, http_code = 401, sha1 = d32f1e47321f14d4391168f7b26ce37f0b585803)
error: Unable to find d32f1e47321f14d4391168f7b26ce37f0b585803 under http://johnuser@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject
Cannot obtain needed blob d32f1e47321f14d4391168f7b26ce37f0b585803
while processing commit eba6849896d12c9652bbc75ffcbc36ab2fc9a847.
error: Fetch failed.
```

I looked in the `git.mywebsite.com/log/error.log`, and I see the following errors:

```
[Sun Jun 23 13:43:00 2013] [error] [client 11.11.11.11] user johnuser: authentication failure for "/websiteproject/objects/cf/fe85cd3a4af8f2cced2bdddbaed72f150ec568": Password Mismatch
```

As mentioned, I have no problems from any other computer (macs, windows, linux etc..).  I tried running a git gc and git update-server-info.  But the same error resulted on my personal computer.

What's going on?

Additional Info: I have no problem doing a git pull from a url from a different server like `https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.git` .   So it's seems something specific to my server and my computer.

Additional Info2: Ok, I can do a git pull if my origin url is `http://johnuser:mypassword@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject` .   However now when I attempt a git push, the terminal hangs for about 15 minutes before showing me the following errors:

```
Unable to refresh lock for http://johnuser:mypassword@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject/info/refs
LOCK HTTP error 412
```

I looked in the apache error logs and see this:

```
[Sun Jun 23 14:26:36 2013] [error] [client 11.11.11.11] (2)No such file or directory: The precondition(s) specified by the "If:" header did not match this resource. At least one failure is because: a State-token was supplied, but it was not found in the locks on this resource.  [412, #0]
[Sun Jun 23 14:26:36 2013] [error] [client 11.11.11.11] Could not LOCK /websiteproject/info/refs due to a failed precondition (e.g. other locks).  [412, #0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK , i fixed the problem.

First thing I did was change the remote url from `http://johnuser@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject` to `http://johnuser:mypassword@git.mywebsite.com/websiteproject` .  So that is, I put the password right into my url.

That fixed my git pull problem.  However, i was starting to get the 412 lock up.  To fix that, on my computer, i created the file `~/.netrc-file` with the following content:

```
machine git.mywebsite.com
login johnuser
password mypassword
```

Then I was able to do a git push.